# removeAll method for BST (Binary Search Tree)

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, removeall

I have this code below, I'm attempting to create a removeAll method for a Binary Search Tree. I think the code below is most likely readable even without all the outside code and context, but if not, I'll be glad to provide more information. However, this code is simply not working and I cannot figure out the reason for it. I am just trying to iterate through the binary search tree using an in-order traversal, counting the number of times the targetElement exists, and then calling the remove method that number of times.

```
public void removeAllOccurrences(T targetElement) throws ElementNotFoundException 
   {
    removeElement(targetElement);

    Comparable<T> comparableElement = (Comparable<T>) targetElement;
    Iterator<T> iter = iteratorInOrder();
    int n = 0; 


    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        if (((Comparable<T>) comparableElement).equals(iter.next())) 
        {
            n++;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        removeElement(targetElement);
    }


}
```

The name of the class is LinkedBinarySearchTree. We are working with  BinaryTreeNode. We have a getRootNode() method.

Comment: removeElement and iteratorInOrder() work properly if anyone is wondering.

Comment: I've also tried using iter.remove() inside the if statement and then delete the for-statement. Also not removing all occurrences of targetElement.

Comment: Is `n` being incremented at all? That `if` condition to check equality seems a bit off to me.

Comment: @TheGamer007  n is being incremented if the if-condition is true. 
If it finds a match, increment n, else keep n the same.
I know it's off, but I do know exactly why it's off or how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are making the assumption that `T` implements `Comparable<T>` (by casting `targetElement`) you should use this functionality. The `equals` method you are using to compare `comparableElement` and `iter.next()` is a method inherited from the `Object` class and may not have been overridden by `T`. The default implementation of the `equals` method simply compares the memory addresses of the caller and the argument which is probably not what you want.

The `compareTo` method of `Comparable<T>` would actually be implemented by `T` so you should use it instead. `compareTo` returns an `int` which indicates the caller is less than the argument if it is negative, the caller is greater than the argument if it is positive, or the caller is equal to the argument if it is zero. Therefore, you should change the expression `((Comparable<T>) comparableElement).equals(iter.next())` to `comparableElement.compareTo(iter.next()) == 0`. The casting of `comparableElement` isn't necessary because the variable is already of type `Comparable<T>`.

Here is how the change looks in your code.

```
public void removeAllOccurrences(T targetElement) throws ElementNotFoundException {
    removeElement(targetElement);

    Comparable<T> comparableElement = (Comparable<T>) targetElement;
    Iterator<T> iter = iteratorInOrder();
    int n = 0;

    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        if (comparableElement.compareTo(iter.next()) == 0) {
            n++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        removeElement(targetElement);
    }
}
```

Let me know if I have misunderstood your question.